# How to display value in grid column.

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a extJS grid with four column. On third column I am modifying the value by button and able to display. In Fourth column I am getting empty string `""` as data. I am giving some input and trying to save this in store but it not happening. How to save value in extjs grid store.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridID');
    var gridstore = grid.getStore();
    var modify = gridstore.modified;
    for (var i = 0; i < modify.length; i++) {
             modifyRec[i].data.S = "Hello";
}
```

`S` is dataIndex of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use set, than changing property directly.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridID');
var gridstore = grid.getStore();
var modify = gridstore.modified;
for (var i = 0; i < modify.length; i++) {
         modifyRec[i].set('S', "Hello");
}
```

Edit:
In [Ext-data-AbstractStore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/source/AbstractStore.html#Ext-data-AbstractStore) [afterEdit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/source/AbstractStore.html#Ext-data-AbstractStore-method-afterEdit) fires [update](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-update) event. Which is being called from [Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set) [set](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-set)

Comment: I tried the same but not getting. I am getting my values in debugger but in UI it not appearing.

Comment: It is not rendering on screen.

Comment: Can  you please provide a fiddle how its not working. It should work.. Store fires an update event which will refresh the grid. Unless there is something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this values in store(checked in debugger). where is Store fires an update event ?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared some fiddle for you. Hope it will help you:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f56

To get modiified records i used getModifiedRecords() fuction.